# Rails 3 'new' action as the index page due to a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a small app where the index page is a form that instructs the user for their email, I have changed my route so that the root_path is the 'new' action which renders my form:

```
Oa::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :signups
  match "/confirm", :to => "pages#confirm"
  root :to => 'signups#new'
end
```

This is working fine, when I submit the form it is working fine. When I submit on the root page and I cause a validation error the address bar has the url localhost:3000/signups and shows me my validation errors, which is also good but if I were to manually visit http://localhost:3000/signups it gives me an error "The action 'index' could not be found for SignupsController". Would it be ok if I created the 'index' action and redirect_to root_path so that I don't receive the "The action 'index' could not be found for SignupsController" if I were to access http://localhost:3000/signups directly? Is this the proper way to do this?

```
class SignupsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def new
    @signup = Signup.new
  end

  def create
@signup = Signup.new(params[:signup])
if @signup.save
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@signup).deliver
  flash[:notice] = "Signup created successfully."
  redirect_to confirm_path
else
  render :action => "new"
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks!

J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
post '/' => 'signups#create'
root to: 'signups#new'
```

Do not use `resources :signups`

Comment: Delba, That gives me an error No route matches [GET] "/". Also, why would I not use resources? I plan on adding other actions in here later.

Comment: Are you sure? Or `root :to => 'signups#new'`. I gonna update my answer with why you shouldn't use resources in this case

Comment: Ah yes, it does work, root :to => 'signups#new' I made a typo as well. So why shouldn't I use resources?

Comment: I can't manage to explain that clearly (english is not my mother tongue). In short: when a validation error happens, the url is the url of the `create` action (in this case: `POST '/signups'`). It doesn't feel "natural" to see an url which is not accessible via get. So when you don't need a full resource, chose to `POST` to a known url. Is that clear? I doubt..;-)

Comment: Little clarification: I am absolutely not saying that you should **never** use `resources`. In your particular case, if you want pretty routes, don't use it if you just need #new and #create.

Comment: Nah, I get yea, makes sense, I will read up on rails routing. Every book I read is using resources, I guess my case is simpler. I am building some stuff on my own, trial and error :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason that http://localhost:3000/signups gives me an error "The action 'index' could not be found for SignupsController" is because:

The first 'matched' routes is used.
So all of this:

```
match "/confirm", :to => "pages#confirm"
root :to => 'signups#new'
```

is ignored by the /signups URL because IT gets dealt with by

resources :signups

which creates all the routes - index, show, create, new, edit, update, destroy

and when 'signups' is used it implies the signups index action.

Try removing it and/or reading up on [RESTful routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) in rails and apply that.